# UITableViewCell contentView resize when editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

In iOS6, when a table view is in editing mode, the contentView of its cells is adjusted to make place for the additional controls, keeping everything non-overlapping.

In iOS7, the detail disclosure indicator overlaps with the contentView in editing mode.
(see image, the first row is only contentView, the second shows with editing controls.)

[image]).

What is the best way of preventing such overlapping controls? Shouldn't the UITableViewCell adjust the frames accordingly?

Thanks in advance,

Remco Poelstra

Comment: Running into the same issue, will file a bug shortly.

Comment: Have you also noticed the content view resizing animation after the right-hand side delete button is revealed after pressing the left-hand side delete button? Even if the content would look good in your state, it's still going to be screwed up if you try and delete the cell.